Shouldn’t $0$ to any power be undefined?
So one of my younger cousins asked me this today. This is the summed up version of what they said.
We know that for all real numbers $x^{n-1} = \dfrac{x^n}{x}$, because $x^{n+1} = x^n \cdot x$.
So let's say we wanted to find out $0^4$. That should be equal to $\dfrac{0^5}{0}$, but that is undefined because you are dividing by $0$.
I know you can just say $0^4 = 0 \times 0 \times 0 \times 0$, but this means there’s a contradiction in one of the exponent rules.
Where is the flaw with this logic, since I know they are objectively wrong but I can’t think of why?

$x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n}{x}$ unless $x=0$

As Zima pointed out, you cannot use the formula $x^{n-1}=\dfrac{x^n}x$ for $x=0$, hence you cannot deduce that $0^4$ is equal to $\dfrac{0^5}0$ which is undefined.

Um I certainly didn’t expect an answer as simple as you can’t use 0 for the formula. Thanks I guess although now I feel kind of stupid lol

The error is in the statement "We know for all real numbers $x^{n - 1} = \frac{x^n}{x}$, because $x^{n + 1} = x^n \cdot x$." It is true that $x^{n + 1} = x^n \cdot x$, for all $x$ (given at least one of $n > 0$ or $x \neq 0$ holds), but you cannot follow that $x^{n - 1} = \frac{x^n}{x}$; this is true only if $x \neq 0$.
Whenever you want to apply an operation (in this case dividing by $x$), you have to make sure first that you're actually allowed to do that (and possibly exclude cases where you're not). For division, the case is relatively simple: Both of you probably already know that you can divide by any (real) number except for 0, and this precisely tells you that you that you cannot go ahead in the case $x = 0$ and derive your contradiction.
